# How can I parse in the onclick() text in Python3 BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've got the following HTML:

```
<td id="uprnButton0">
  <button type="button"
    onclick="changeText('uprnButton0','Loading');populAddr('14 PLACE NAME TOWN POSTCODE');
    getobject('divAddress').innerHTML = '';
    GetInfoAndRoundsFor('123456789123','SWN');" 
    title="Get Calendar for this address"
    >Show
  </button>
</td>
```

I want to get the text in populAddr and in GetInfoAndRoundsFor i.e. the strings "14 PLACE NAME TOWN POSTCODE" and "123456789123" respectively.

So far I have tried:

```
button_click_text = address.find('button').get('onclick')
```

Which gets me the full onClick string which is great.  Is the only way to get the specific sub strings doing a bit of slicing?

I've tried this:

```
   string = """changeText('uprnButton1','Loading');populAddr('14 PLACE NAME TOWN POSTCODE');getobject('divAddress').innerHTML = '';GetInfoAndRoundsFor('123456789123','SWN');"""
    string_before = "populAddr('"
    string_after = "');getobject"

    print(string[string.index(string_before)+len(string_before):string.index(string_after)])
```

Which does work but looks like an effing mess.  Is there best practice here?

Actually just thought this might be better:

```
string_split = string.split("'")
print(string_split[5])
print(string_split[11])
```

Comment: I was writing an answer with split, I think it's the good way to go

Comment: Read about [re.Match.group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be the quickest way of doing it and because I guess the HTML could be switched I put a couple of checks in to make sure the house number was what I searched for and the uprn was actually a number.  If either of these was false then I know the code on the site has probably been tweaked:

```
string_split = string.split("'")
address = string_split[5]
uprn = string_split[11]
```

## validate address starts with correct house number

```
print(address.startswith('15 '))
```

## validate uprn contains a number

```
print(uprn[0:12].isdigit())
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the following two lazy regex patterns

```
import re

html ='''<td id="uprnButton0">
  <button type="button"
    onclick="changeText('uprnButton0','Loading');populAddr('14 PLACE NAME TOWN POSTCODE');
    getobject('divAddress').innerHTML = '';
    GetInfoAndRoundsFor('123456789123','SWN');" 
    title="Get Calendar for this address"
    >Show
  </button>
</td>'''

p1 =re.compile(r"populAddr\('(.*?)'")
p2 = re.compile(r"GetInfoAndRoundsFor\('(.*?)'")
print(p1.findall(html)[0])
print(p2.findall(html)[0])
```

Explanation for one (same principle for both)

[image]

you can replace `html` variable with `response.text` or `button_click_text`where response.text is the `requests` response `.text`

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find(button)` returns an object representing the first `button` element, and `soup.find('button')['onclick']` returns the string value of the `onclick` attribute.

Because of this, there isn't a convenient way of fetching the value of `populAddr`, other than using `split`.

I would recommend splitting by the following:

```
address = address.find('button').get('onclick').split('populAddr(')[1].split(')')[0]
```

If you split by `populAddr`, you know exactly what index the address is located in (it will always be index 0).

If you split by `'`, you will have to manually review every page you scrape in order to verify that the address will end up in index 5.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the question of OP

Comment: I like this idea but I get "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: @JohnnyJohnBoy Sorry about that.  I forgot to add `[1]` to the first split call.  My updated call should work.

Answer (score 0):

That is my try:

```
In [1]: d = """
   ...: <td id="uprnButton0">
   ...:   <button type="button"
   ...:     onclick="changeText('uprnButton0','Loading');populAddr('14 PLACE NAME TOWN POSTCODE');
   ...:     getobject('divAddress').innerHTML = '';
   ...:     GetInfoAndRoundsFor('123456789123','SWN');"
   ...:     title="Get Calendar for this address"
   ...:     >Show
   ...:   </button>
   ...: </td>
   ...: """

In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

In [3]: soup = bs(d,"lxml")

In [4]: button_click_text = soup.find('button').get('onclick')

In [5]: button_click_text
Out[5]: "changeText('uprnButton0','Loading');populAddr('14 PLACE NAME TOWN POSTCODE');\n    getobject('divAddress').innerHTML = '';\n    GetInfoAndRoundsFor('123456789123','SWN');"

In [6]: import re
   ...: regex = re.compile(r"'.*?'")
   ...: out = regex.findall(button_click_text)
   ...: s1 = out[2][1:-1]
   ...: s2 = out[-2][1:-1]

In [7]: s1
Out[7]: '14 PLACE NAME TOWN POSTCODE'

In [8]: s2
Out[8]: '123456789123'
```

Comment: This didn't work for me and I got no output from print s1 or s2.